# Can I get more amps than SMPS is rated?

Tags: voltage, current, switch-mode-power-supply, watts

An SMPS is rated at 12 V and 30 A, 360 watts as output.

If I step down the voltage to 5 V and use this 5 V with a device consuming 70 A, can this SMPS deliver 70 A of current with 5 V, 350 W, even if rated for 30 A?

Comment: Almost certainly not.   There's more to it than power equivalency.   For starters, the transistors used to control the switching action probably aren't up to the job .  (i.e. they'll melt from that much current)

Comment: What do you mean by "step down"? 350W out for 360W in (97.5% efficiency) is likely challenging. And, you have no margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supply you have provides a 12V, 30A output. That's it. The supply doesn't know nor care what you do with that power. It doesn't "know" that you're stepping it down to 5V.

Realistically speaking, you can bet on getting 5V, 300W out of a buck converter that's fed with 12V, 30A. That's not hard, and you can probably even buy a pre-made module or a couple and parallel them.

To get 350W at 5V out of 12V, the 12V supply would need to be 450W. That's because it needs derating as well - you shouldn't be running it non-stop at 100% load. The buck converters would need to be rated for at least 400W total as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you used a 95% efficient buck regulator you would be able to get about 340 watts but this would be a very sophisticated design. I don't think that a design that drops the voltage from 12 volts to 5 volts is available with a power efficiency of \$\frac{35}{360} = 0.972\$ without considerable investment in time and dedication to reach what you want.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your Answer, I actually need 5V over 20 meters. so due to `voltage drop` I thought for supplying 12V and convert to 5V at the end, If no other way, I will find SMPS rated 12V & ~40amps as sated by Kuba for getting 350W.